# Приостановка, затем возобновление потока в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, task

Изучаю Java, собственно вопрос - как можно с помощью элементов управления JavaFX приостановить, а затем возобновить поток? На примере программы, которая отображает время ... как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки Pause - время остановилось, а после Continue - возобновилось?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.concurrent.*;

public class TaskTest extends Application {

    Label lbTask;
    Button btnPause, btnContinue;

    Thread th;
    boolean stopFlag;

    SimpleDateFormat fHHMMSS = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            for( ; ; ) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    lbTask.setText(fHHMMSS.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));                    
                });         
                if(stopFlag)
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };    

    public void start(Stage myStage) {

        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 240, 70);   // создать сцену
        myStage.setScene(myScene);  // установить сцену на платформе

        lbTask = new Label("Время: ");
        btnPause = new Button("Pause");
        btnContinue = new Button("Continue");

        th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();

        rootNode.getChildren().addAll(lbTask, btnPause, btnContinue);
        myStage.show(); 

        btnPause.setOnAction((ae) -> {
            // приостановить поток
        });

        btnContinue.setOnAction((ae) -> {
            // Возобновить поток            
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Нечестное", но простое решение - добавить флаг паузы (`pauseFlag`):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.concurrent.*;

public class TaskTest extends Application {

    Label lbTask;
    Button btnPause, btnContinue;

    Thread th;
    boolean stopFlag;

    SimpleDateFormat fHHMMSS = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    boolean pauseFlag;

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            for( ; ; ) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    lbTask.setText(fHHMMSS.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                while (pauseFlag) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    if (stopFlag)
                        break;
                }
                if(stopFlag)
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    public void start(Stage myStage) {

        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 240, 70);   // создать сцену
        myStage.setScene(myScene);  // установить сцену на платформе

        lbTask = new Label("Время: ");
        btnPause = new Button("Pause");
        btnContinue = new Button("Continue");

        th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();

        rootNode.getChildren().addAll(lbTask, btnPause, btnContinue);
        myStage.show();

        btnPause.setOnAction((ae) -> {
            // "приостановить" поток
            pauseFlag = true;
        });

        btnContinue.setOnAction((ae) -> {
            // "Возобновить" поток
            pauseFlag = false;
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopFlag = false;
    }
}
```

А "по-честному" нужно использовать синхронизацию потоков, например, с помощью wait+notify+synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал через `javafx.concurrent.Service`, но это всё равно приведет к многократному созданию тасков.

```
Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                for( ; ; ) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        lbTask.setText(fHHMMSS.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    });
                    if(stopFlag)
                        break;
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};

/* ... */

service.restart();

btnPause.setOnAction((ae) -> {
    if ( !service.isRunning() )
        return;
//  stopFlag = true;
//  тут бы подождать нормальное завершение
//  if ( service.isRunning() )
        service.cancel();
});

btnContinue.setOnAction((ae) -> {
    if ( service.isRunning() )
        return;
//  stopFlag = false;
    service.restart();
});
```